# Create new attribute in a dataframe on certain calculation

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

Consider a dataframe as below:

| customerid | segment |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | active |
| 1 | viewed |
| 1 | addtocart |
| 1 | transacted |
| 2 | active |
| 2 | viewed |
| 2 | addtocart |
| 3 | active |
| 3 | viewed |
| 4 | active |
| 5 | active |

If we see:

active segment has: 5 customerids
viewed has 3
addtocart has 2
transacted has 1

What is want is:

For customerid 1: this user falls in all the above segments, i would want to create one more column in the dataframe and give rank 1(since this has least count of customerids) to transacted segment for customerid , similarly for other customerids, we get a dataframe as below

| customerid | segment | Segment Priority |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | active | 4 |
| 1 | viewed | 3 |
| 1 | addtocart | 2 |
| 1 | transacted | 1 |
| 2 | active | 3 |
| 2 | viewed | 2 |
| 2 | addtocart | 1 |
| 3 | active | 2 |
| 3 | viewed | 1 |
| 4 | active | 1 |
| 5 | active | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

First, make a second dataframe with a ranking of the value counts of segment types:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['segment'].value_counts().rank(ascending=True)).reset_index()
df2.columns = ['segment', 'count_rank']
```

df2:

| segment | count_rank |
| --- | --- |
| active | 4.0 |
| viewed | 3.0 |
| addtocart | 2.0 |
| transacted | 1.0 |

You can join this dataframe with your original dataframe:

`df3 = df.merge(df2, on='segment').sort_values(['customerid', 'count_rank'], ascending=[True, False])`

| customerid | segment | count_rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | active | 4.0 |
| 1 | viewed | 3.0 |
| 1 | addtocart | 2.0 |
| 1 | transacted | 1.0 |
| 2 | active | 4.0 |
| 2 | viewed | 3.0 |
| 2 | addtocart | 2.0 |
| 3 | active | 4.0 |
| 3 | viewed | 3.0 |
| 4 | active | 4.0 |
| 5 | active | 4.0 |

However, this is incorrect, since you want the ranking per customerid.
Luckily we can use this new column to make a new ranking:

`df3['Segment Priority'] = df3.groupby('customerid')['count_rank'].rank()`

To make it a bit more pretty reset index, drop the helper column and make Segment Priority an int type:

```
df3.reset_index(drop=True).drop('count_rank', axis=1)
df3['Segment Priority'] = df3['Segment Priority'].astype(int)
```

Result:

| customerid | segment | Segment Priority |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | active | 4 |
| 1 | viewed | 3 |
| 1 | addtocart | 2 |
| 1 | transacted | 1 |
| 2 | active | 3 |
| 2 | viewed | 2 |
| 2 | addtocart | 1 |
| 3 | active | 2 |
| 3 | viewed | 1 |
| 4 | active | 1 |
| 5 | active | 1 |

Of course it is possible to do it in fewer steps, or adding df2 directly to df. However, this way I think it is most clear what happens.